# Ubuntu 18.04 got scrambled screen after resume

Tags: suspend, display, 18.04, resume

I just upgraded to 18.04. everything works fine except when I resume from the suspended mode, the screen got scrambled. sometimes,switched to the terminal mode showing; starting firmware update.....then stuck there forever. The only thing I can do is to reboot machine.